# Capifony / Capistrano: Symlink Cannot Be Created

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

I'm deploying a Symfony 2 project, to Amazon EC2, using Capifony 2.2.7.  The `shared_children` option in `deploy.rb` attempts to create symlinks for the `logs`, `uploads` and `vendor` directories, but hangs on the `uploads` directory (after successfully creating the link to `logs` and `vendor`).  The verbose output of `cap:deploy` looks like this:

```
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' sh -c 'if [ -d /home/ubuntu/tempdeploy/releases/20130224230816/web/uploads ] ; then rm -rf /home/ubuntu/tempdeploy/releases/20130224230816/web/uploads; fi'"
servers: ["10.12.345.67"]
[10.12.345.67] executing command
* executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ln -nfs /home/ubuntu/tempdeploy/shared/web/uploads /home/ubuntu/tempdeploy/releases/20130224230816/web/uploads"
** [out :: 10.12.345.67] ln:
** [out :: 10.12.345.67] failed to create symbolic link `/home/ubuntu/tempdeploy/releases/20130224230816/web/uploads'
** [out :: 10.12.345.67] : No such file or directory
```

I've tried deleting `.rsync_cache`, deploying via `:copy`, etc.  The `web/uploads` directory exists in the git repo.  Here's [the full deploy.rb file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5026198).

Any ideas, or more info I can provide?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am having the same problem...

Comment: Have you tried checking the inode usage via the `df -i` command?